# Django CreateView customise form default field based on url parameter

Tags: python, django, django-forms, create-view

file: Capacity/models.py

```
class Env(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    def get_absolute_url(self):
            return reverse('index')

class Envhosts(models.Model):
    env =  models.ForeignKey(Env)
    hostname = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    count = models.IntegerField()

    class Meta:
        unique_together = ("env","hostname")

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('index')
```

file: Capacity/views.py

```
 class EnvhostsCreate(CreateView):
    model = Capacity.models.Envhosts
    fields=['env','hostname','count']
    template_name_suffix = '_create_form'
```

file Capacity/urls.py:

```
urlpatterns = patterns(........ url(r'^createhosts/(?P<envid>\d+)/$',EnvhostsCreate.as_view(),name='envhosts_create'))
```

So now, 
when i open this form: 
`/Capacity/createhosts/3/` (where 3 is my env id)
It shows an option of env objects as a drop down list based on the number of object of Env. But i want it to take the env on its own based on the env id ('3' in this case)

I know i have to override some method in class EnvhostsCreate(CreateView). But i m unable to figure out which method and how to take the env based on the part after `/createhosts/`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the pattern described in [the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/topics/class-based-views/generic-editing/#models-and-request-user) for adding request.user - it's the same principle. Remove `env` from the fields list, then define `form_valid()`:

```
class EnvhostsCreate(CreateView):
    model = Capacity.models.Envhosts
    fields = ['hostname', 'count']
    template_name_suffix = '_create_form'

    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.env = Envhosts.objects.get(pk=self.kwargs['envid'])
        return super(EnvhostsCreate, self).form_valid(form)
```

Comment: Works perfectly. Had to format a little  
  
form.instance.env = Env.objects.get(pk=self.kwargs['envid']) 
(since its a foriegn key for Env class)

Comment: To set a default value but still let the user decide, [`get_initial`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13180116/how-do-i-set-initial-data-on-a-django-class-based-generic-createview-with-reques) might be a good alternative.

Comment: here's the link for [Django 4.6](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/topics/class-based-views/generic-editing/#models-and-request-user)