# Url key word argument within CreateView

Tags: python, django

How do I get a URL keyword argument with `get()` or another method of CreateView? I tried to use `self.kwargs['arg_name']`, but without result.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: may be `self.request.GET.get('arg_name')` ?

Comment: What is the URL pattern of the view?

Comment: @Alasdair, `url(r'^lot/create/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/$', views.LotCreate.as_view(), name='lot-create')`

Comment: Then you want `self.kwargs['pk']`. If that doesn't work, then you need to explain what the problem is in more detail -- it's not clear what you mean by 'without result'.

Comment: @Alasdair, self.kwargs['pk'] it's returned None.

Comment: What url are you going to in your browser?

Comment: @Alasdair `127.0.0.1:8000/lot/create/2/`

Comment: As several people have said, `self.kwargs['pk']` should simply work. You'll need to add more information on how to reproduce the problem. Perhaps a different URL pattern is matching the URL first.

Answer (score 0):

You can access url keywords in view by using following code

**Method one**

To access the url parameters in class based views, use `self.args` or `self.kwargs` so you would access it by doing `self.kwargs['user_id']`

```
url(r'^users/(?P<user_id>[0-9]+)/$',
views.your_view_name.as_view()),
```

In youe views.py:

```
class your_class_name(CreateView):
    def view_name(self):
        upk=self.kwargs.get['user_id']
        print user_id
        ...
```

**Method 2**

If you are passing keyword in url like this

```
/your_url?user_id=1
```

views.py

```
def view_name(request):
    user_id = request.GET.get('user_id')
    print user_id
    ....
```

Reference from [Stackoverflow Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20421017/django-createview-customise-form-default-field-based-on-url-parameter)

hope this helps you

Comment: This solution isn't fit to working with class vased views. I'm using CreateView to create objects, and i need to get url key word arguments precisely within CreateView

Comment: Again not that. By your example we get kwargs within ListView (in ListView I getting kwargs succesfully), but I need to repeat this procedure pewcisely within CreateView

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean this ?

```
class CreateMessageView(LoginRequiredMixin, CreateView):

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        ret = super(CreateMessageView, self).get(request, *args, **kwargs)
        upk=self.kwargs['user_id']
        return ret
```

I have tested it... working ... NIKHILS RANEs answer is somewhat correct. this line  `upk=self.kwargs['user_id']` differs from his `upk=self.kwargs.get['user_id']`. Maybe thats your problem

Comment: No, I tried exactly `self.kwargs['some']`, and your example returne `super(CreateMessageView, self).get(request, *args, **kwargs)`, but how we can use upk in this case?

Comment: it is `self.kwargs['pk']` in your case. If you wanna use `'some'` or `'upk'`you will have to specify `r'^lot/create/(?P<some>[0-9]+)/$'` or `r'^lot/create/(?P<upk>[0-9]+)/$'` it it does not help I do not understand your problem. If you wanna use upk somewhere else in your view use `self.upk=self.kwargs['upk']`

Comment: Yes, I use `self.kwargs['pk']`, and I already tried it within get() and get_context_data() methods of CreateView, but I get the same result, `self.kwargs['pk']` nothing returns.

Comment: And within url pattern I'm using `pk` variable name.

Comment: I am sure that I am right. Please start a debbuger and examine the variables inside your get method. You have a silly fault here.

Comment: I try to check by exist pk variable in `self.kwargs` by `if 'pk' in self.kwargs:` and body of if statement not running

Comment: please check the key, value pairs of the dict like this : `for k, v in self.kwargs.items():
    print(k, v)`