# Django: Passing Kwargs as form Values to generic CBV Form

Tags: python, django, forms

I have a form in which the value of the first field can be determined by the URL. ie: `example.com/value/form` in which `value` is the appropriate response to the first field on the form.

How can I pass this value to the form on the page?

```
class VarietyCreate(CreateView):
    template_name = "generic_create.html"
    model = Variety
    form_class = VarietyForm
    pk_url_kwarg = "pk"
    initial = {"product_group" : pk_url_kwarg}

    def get_success_url(self):
        return reverse("purchases:Variety Index", kwargs={'pk': self.kwargs.get('pk')})
```

What I have does not seem to work.

From my URLs:

```
url(r'^commodities/view/(?P<pk>[^\/]+)/create/$', views.VarietyCreate.as_view(), name='Variety Create'),
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the answer based on [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13180116/how-do-i-set-initial-data-on-a-django-class-based-generic-createview-with-reques).

```
class VarietyCreate(CreateView):
    template_name = "generic_create.html"
    model = Variety
    form_class = VarietyForm

    def get_initial(self):
        return {"product_group" : self.kwargs.get('pk')}

    def get_success_url(self):
        return reverse("purchases:Variety Index", kwargs={'pk': self.kwargs.get('pk')})
```